# String comparison in freemarker not working

Tags: java, freemarker

```
<#if ${primaryName!}?has_content> && ${key?js_string!}=="Joe">
//do something

<#elseif ${primaryClass!}?has_content> && ${key?js_string!}=="Apple">
//do something

<#else>
//do something

</#if>
```

The above gives me error that something is expected at the end. { ] && . Whats wrong in the above?

```
Encountered "{" at line 26, column 39 in abc.ftl. Was expecting one of: ">" ... "." ... "[" ... "(" ... "?" ... "!" ... <TERMINATING_EXCLAM> ... "??" ... "+" ... "-" ... "*" ... "/" ... "%" ... "!=" ... "=" ... "==" ... ">=" ... <ESCAPED_GTE> ... ">" ... <ESCAPED_GT> ... <LESS_THAN_EQUALS> ... <LESS_THAN> ... ".." ... <AND> ... <OR> ...
```

Comment: can you share the exact error message?

Comment: Encountered "{" at line 26, column 39 in abc.ftl.
Was expecting one of:
    ">" ...
    "." ...
    "[" ...
    "(" ...
    "?" ...
    "!" ...
    <TERMINATING_EXCLAM> ...
    "??" ...
    "+" ...
    "-" ...
    "*" ...
    "/" ...
    "%" ...
    "!=" ...
    "=" ...
    "==" ...
    ">=" ...
    <ESCAPED_GTE> ...
    ">" ...
    <ESCAPED_GT> ...
    <LESS_THAN_EQUALS> ...
    <LESS_THAN> ...
    ".." ...
    <AND> ...
    <OR> ...

Comment: Shared the error messgae Matthew Wilson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Absolutely it will give you some thing like this

```
Encountered "{" ...
Was expecting one of:
    ">" ...
    "." ...
    "[" ...
    "(" ...
    "?" ...
    "!" ...
```

Because if else syntax is not correct, there are couple of things wrong.

Highlighted are are wrong thing in below line.

*<#if `$`{primaryName`!`}?has_content`>` && ${key?js_string!}=="Joe">*

you put the data in data model but in template for if/else foreach, list you can access it direct not with the ${}

Here is correct , for equality use `==` for  uneqality use `!=`

```
<#if primaryName?has_content && key?is_string && key=="Joe">
 // do somthing
<#elseif primaryClass?has_content && key?is_string && key=="Apple">
// elseif do something
<#else>
// else do something
</#if>
```

**has_content** return true. see [doc](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_expert.html)

```
Note that when your data-model implements multiple template model interfaces you may get unexpected results. However, when in doubt you can use always use expr!?size > 0 or expr!?length > 0 instead of expr?has_content.

There is no js_string method , but its is is_string return true, if value is string
```

see doc for [is_string](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_expert.html)

Further see  `matches` [Built-ins for strings](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_matches)

Comment: @user35736644892 There is a "js_string" method which escapes JavaScript characters, and it has nothing to do with "is_string". I just mentioned this in case the OP wanted to compare the string values after escaping javascript characters.